# Displaying svg images in a boxdecoration widget

Tags: flutter, widget

I'm trying to display an svg image in a box decoration but I'm getting an erorr

I tried to wrap the decoration with a .image and tried saving the svg image in a widget and passing it. This is the code:

```
ListTile(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, // Remove default padding
      leading: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 35,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/images/ash-logo-red.svg',
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      title: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4, // Set width here
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      trailing: const Text("hi")),
```

Comment: it does. Thank you